# Unable to get Facebook user info (birthday, work, education)

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm having a hard time getting a user's information via Facebook SDK.

I'm trying to get the birthday, work and education.

I'm using this:

```
 let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"education, work, email, id, name, first_name, last_name, birthday, gender"])
```

That call does not provide the education, work or birthday.

I have the following permissions approved by Facebook:

- user_birthday
- user_education_history
- user_work_history

When I try to use those values in the code example above, the app crashes with a nonexisting field :

```
type (User), com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode=100, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 100;
            "fbtrace_id" = CVy14JLKraa;
            message = "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (user_birthday) on node type (User)";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 400;
}}
```

When I try to use a graph request with a user ID versus me:

```
let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/\(fbid)", parameters: ["fields":"user_birthday"])
                    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in ...
```

I also get the same error:

```
 message = "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (user_birthday) on node type (User)";
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no field called user_birthday.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40082252/6656894 refer this answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40816501/6656894 and also refer this answer

Comment: _“I have the following permissions approved by Facebook”_ - and did the user grant them to your app …?

Answer (score 0):

Please Do as Follow.
Might be work for you.

```
#define K_Field @"fields"
#define K_Permission @"email,location, birthday, name, link"
#define K_ID @"id"
#define K_Name @"name"
#define K_DOB @"birthday"
#define K_Email @"email"



        FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
        [login logOut];
        login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorWeb;

        [login
         logInWithReadPermissions: @[K_Email]
         fromViewController:self
         handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *user, NSError *error) {
             if (error || user.isCancelled) {
                 NSLog(@"Process error");
             } else {
                 if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
                     [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{K_Field: K_Permission}]
                      startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                          if (!error) {
                              NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);
                              //Done login
                          }
                      }];
                 }
             }
         }];
```

Please Make sure You have use right keyword Same as [facebook official docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_birthday)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using the Facebook Graph API by collecting the user’s id and getting the public details from the Graph API access:

```
$fb->get('/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email,birthday');
```